# QR scanner crashes

Tags: android, eclipse

Does Zxing latest lib support lower end devices like my Android 2.3.6?

I am not able to scan Qrcode, having minSdkversion=10 and targetSdkversion=18

```
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.InactivityTimer.onActivity(InactivityTimer.java:52)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.InactivityTimer.<init>(InactivityTimer.java:46)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:139)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at 
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-21 16:00:54.382: E/AndroidRuntime(7464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right there in the log you posted:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
```

It's literally telling you that there is no field called THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR in the class `AsyncTask`. And if you look at [**the documentation for this field**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) you will see this:

> **public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR**
>   Added in API level 11
>   An Executor that can be used to execute tasks in
>   parallel.

The important part here being **ADDED IN API LEVEL 11**. So no, whatever that library is doing there only works from API level 11 (Android 3.0 Honeycomb) and above.

But I guess this might just be a bug, parallel execution was the default in earlier Android versions. I don't know why the library doesn't just fallback on that implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your valueable rply